# Copy Image files from old folder to new folder using PHP

Tags: php

I want to copy all image files from my images folder to new folder using PHP. I tried the code below but having errors.

```
<?php
 $old_dir = 'images/';
 $new_dir = 'images/new_update';
 $scanned_directory = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($old_dir));

 foreach ($scanned_directory as $key ) {    
    $source_file = $old_dir.$key;
    $destination_path = $new_dir;

    if(rename($source_file.'/'.$key,$destination_path.'/'.$key))
       echo "Success";
    else 
       echo "Fail";    
 }
?>
```

> Error: Warning: rename(images/Screenshot 2019-02-04 at 1.24.35 PM.png/Screenshot 2019-02-04 at 1.24.35 PM.png,images/del//Screenshot 2019-02-04 at 1.24.35 PM.png): Not a directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/spartanlink/news/gallery/scandir.php on line 12

I don't know why I am getting that error. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think you can just rename folders, create a new folder and put one folder inside the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing `$key` twice, once when defining `$source_file` and once when calling `rename`. It should be more like this:

```
$source_file = $old_dir.$key;
$destination_path = $new_dir;

if(rename($source_file,$destination_path.'/'.$key))
   echo "Success";
```

Comment: Made the correction and now getting 
`Warning: rename(images/Screenshot 2019-02-04 at 1.24.35 PM.png,images/del/Screenshot 2019-02-04 at 1.24.35 PM.png): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/spartanlink/news/gallery/scandir.php on line 12
Fail

Warning: rename(images/del,images/del/del): Invalid argument in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/spartanlink/news/gallery/scandir.php on line 12
Fail`

Comment: You need read and write permissions in the source and destination folder.

Comment: Worked for me after giving permissions. Thanks